# Springboot save hashmap in mongo repository

Tags: java, mongodb, hashmap, azure-cosmosdb, mongorepository

I have an entity class that has a hashmap field :

```java
@Document(collection = "tenant")
@Getter() @Setter @ToString
public class Tenant extends DateAudit {
    @Id
    private String tenantId=UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Field("name")
    private String name;

    @Field("app_registration_list")
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<AppRegistration>> appRegistrationList = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<AppRegistration>>();
}
```

But while adding data to the field `appRegistrationList` I get this error on my controller:

```
"Invalid BSON field name $hashCodeCache"
```

I am using Microsoft Cosmos Db instead of mongoDb. As read in another issue, my key is also a string value. Not sure what can be changed. I am open to changing the data type that will still satisfy this key and list purpose.

---

EDIT:
I can see this code working if I change the field to the following:

```java
@Field("app_registration_list")
private HashMap<String,String> appRegistrationList = new HashMap<>();
```

However, this doesn't solve the purpose I was looking for.

---

Comment: Does it work if you drop the `$` character from the field name?  (Unclear where that is coming from given the limited details in the question, seemingly some data that gets populated inside of that hash map?)

Comment: I think $hashcodecache is some. internal db thing. my field name is app_registration_list (confirmed it in db too).